# how to apply multiple query on multiple queryset in django

Tags: python, django

I wrote a query which is fetching some details

```
toll_obj = Toll.objects.filter(driver__profile__invoice_number=(invoice_number))
```

Here `toll_obj` can be multiple queryset, one field is common for all objects in `qs(toll_obj)` that is `form_date`. So I want to apply one more condition here which is `form_date<=today` . 
So what can be the best way to achieve this.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to filter Toll objects based on driver's invoice number and with form date less than today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple conditions in a filter method.

```
import datetime

toll_obj = Toll.objects.filter(driver__profile__invoice_number=(invoice_number), form_date__lte=datetime.datetime.today().date())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `__lte` (less then or equal) with a `date` object

```
from django.utils.timezone import datetime

toll_obj = toll_obj.filter(form_date__lte=datetime.today().date())
```

Comment: how to apply this query to existing query together.  is there any way to apply filter once only and get the result